# Permissions Windows Folder

Tags: powershell, permissions, windows-10

I can't seem to figure out how to get full control of my Windows folder.
I want to delete a map in my Windows folder and that map contains other maps and files.

I know how to do it manually but I want to do it in PowerShell but have no idea.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a "map"? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried Get-NTFSAccess and googled a bit but no results... :/ 
I Use W10 and want to remove some maps in my windowsapp folder 
and I know the risks of deleting things, just can't seem to find the command to do it...

Comment: Again, what is a map in this context?

Comment: C:\Windows\InfusedApps\Applications

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031552/how-do-you-take-file-ownership-with-powershell It probably doesn't really matter what folder/file it is or whether it's to do anything with maps.