# C# Can't take ownership of some registry keys

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I'm unable to take ownership of some keys in the registry with my C# code.

I'm trying take ownership on

> Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}

My app is launched as administrator with the `requireAdministrator` flag on the `app.manifest`.

UAC is disabled to test without this security that might interfere.

I'm setting the token `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` properly on my process (Process Explorer confirms me that is enabled on my process).

But when I'm running my code it returns a null key at the `OpenSubKey` call. 
Here is my method :

```
public void takeKeyOwnership(RegistryHive root, string path)
        {
            RegistryKey RootKey = GetKey(root);
            var key = RootKey.OpenSubKey(path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.TakeOwnership);

            if(key == null)
            {
                logger.Warn("[takeKeyOwnership] Unable to take ownership on key " + root + "\\" + path);
                return;
            }
            var acl = key.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.None);
            var localAdmins = new SecurityIdentifier(Constants.LocalAdministratorsSID);
            acl.SetOwner(localAdmins);
            key.SetAccessControl(acl);
            key.Close();
        }
```

My question is different from : [How do I programmatically give ownership of a Registry Key to Administrators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448390) as I've set the SeTakeOwnerShipPrivilege as specified earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically give ownership of a Registry Key to Administrators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448390/how-do-i-programmatically-give-ownership-of-a-registry-key-to-administrators)

Comment: What is the "Target CPU" setting for your project? See more ->  [Why is OpenSubKey() returning null on my Windows 7 64-bit system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464358/why-is-opensubkey-returning-null-on-my-windows-7-64-bit-system)

Comment: My psychic powers suggest you're running [as a 32-bit process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @BobSwager no I've seen this question and I've set the SeTakeOwnership Privilege.

Comment: @Rostech 
I'm running as a 32-bit process yes but I'm opening the registry with RegistryView.Registry32 and modifying 64bits keys on the Wow6432Node when needed.

Comment: @Jonathan, Please check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698274/7406606).  You will need to specify the RegistryView parameter.

Comment: @Rostech yes but if I want to manage 32bits keys too (because this key exists in the 32bit view too) ? If I can be sure Windows always use the 64bit view I'm okay with going full 64bits.

Comment: @Rostech I just tried on 64bit view and it doesn't work either.